# ng-grid. How to hide group column?

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

How to hide group column in data area of ng-grid control (angular-ui)?

for example:

data has two columns: name, age
I want see result like this:

```
-27 (1)
  Martin 
-29 (2)
  Helga
  Alex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the column definitions, set the field's visibility to false:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'age', visible: false },
                  ... ],
    ...,
    groups: ['age'],
}
```

See the ColumnDefs Options at http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/.